# Receive emails from multiple accounts using mailman gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pop3, mailman-gem

Is there a way to receive email from multiple accounts in mailman gem?
Here is my mailman_server.rb which processes mail from a single account

```
require "rubygems"
require "mailman"

Mailman.config.pop3 = {
   server: 'pop.gmail.com', port: 995, ssl: true,
   username: "email@gmail.com",
   password: "password"
}

Mailman::Application.run do
default do
  puts message.subject
end
end
```

I want to receive mails from both email1@gmail.com and email2@gmail.com which I can then process. Is there a way I can open multiple accounts in a single process of mailman?

Comment: I fear you'll need several instances of mailman

Answer (score 3):

1. Create 3rd email account
2. set email forwarding from (email1@gmail.com and email2@gmail.com) to that account
3. set up mailman )